# LTTng and Babeltrace python bindings never enabled

Tags: lttng, babeltrace

I have installed LTTng and Babeltrace followed by the instructions of

sudo apt-get install lttng-tools
sudo apt-get install lttng-modules-dkms 
sudo apt-get install liblttng-ust-dev
sudo apt-get install babeltrace

but the python bindings never work, when i try to import python modlues.

any idea about how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

The python bindings are packaged separately, in the "python3-babeltrace" package. On Ubuntu it's only available since 14.10. If you are on a previous version you can use the [LTTng PPA](https://launchpad.net/~lttng/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) to get it.